# Some how My array only goes through exactly 1/2

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

For some reason what I put in my input tag in my html exactly 1/2 of my array is processed  .
So my input collects the number/letters and assigns a line of code .
for example

```
let result  = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(answers2).map(([k, v]) => [k, MSamples[v] ])
);
```

For simplicity sake
lets say you put in asdf which would equal

```
0: ['M20']
1: ['M30']
2:['M40']
3: ['M50']
length 4
```

so in a for loop

```
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(result).length; i++) { }
```

for some reason it would only print

```
0: ['M20']
1: ['M30']
```

Even if you disable all the code in the for statement and only do a console.log('wow')
it will only console.log wow two times.

EDIT so people want a reproducible example so here is everything you need.

```js
var MSamples = {
  "A": [
    "M10",
  ],
  "B": [
    "M20",
  ],
  "C": [
    "M30",
  ],
  "D": [
    'M40',
  ],
}

var answers2 = document.getElementById('fname').value;

let result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(answers2).map(([k, v]) => [k, MSamples[v]])
);

for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(result).length; i++) {
  console.log('wow');
}
```

```html
<form class="form1 " action="">
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="ABCD">
</form>
```

EDIT FOUND THE ANSWER

So it seems the problem is that I can not put i++; . I took out all instances of i++; and it all worked. at the end of my for statement .

Comment: Object does not have `length`, you are looking into array. Can you provide minimal example for use to check what's wrong?

Comment: Sure the length is to detect how many objects are in the array .
In the example above that would be a length of 4.

So it would be
for (let i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) { }
so the for loop would go through 4 times

if I do  console.log('wow')
it should console.log wow 4 times.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Please provide a reproducible example showing the problem in an inline-runnable snippet, thank you!

Comment: @Justinas OP is checking length of `Object.keys()` which is an array.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) preferably in a code snippet that will run properly

Comment: @Rojo their I edited everything that you need . Thank you for your help,

Answer (score -1):

I could not reproduce this directly using your example, but I might have an idea of what is going on. Do you have another element somewhere in your DOM with the same id `fname`?

`document.getElementById('fname')` will return the first element with that id that it encounters, and if that element's `value` is two characters long than your code will use that length in the for-loop.

Comment: It's just a guess and does not answer OP question

Answer (score -1):

So it seems the problem is that I can not put i++; . I took out all instances of i++;
and it all worked. at the end of my for statement ..

Comment: You only need to add `i++` inside of the brackets when using a while loop